# Looks like this if condition is not working

Tags: conditional-content

I want a query to be executed IF the following condition is true...
but looks like the query is executed anyways.

`if($post->post_parent = '302'){

// Query goes here

}`

Is this query fine?? I want to executed the query if the parent page of current page is 302.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution worked

`$query2= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE ID='$post->ID' AND post_parent=302");

$numrows2 = mysql_num_rows($query2);

if($numrows2 != 0) {

// query goes here

}`

Comment: You shouldn't normally be writing SQL queries in WordPress. Instead, use the API. In this case, you should have used [get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/get_posts). When you do need to write queries, use [WPDB](http://codex.wordpress.org/wpdb) instead of interacting directly with MySQL.

Comment: is there any significant drawback of it ??

Comment: One of the biggest is that your queries could break after an upgrade if the database schema changes. Another big one is that you miss out on the internal caching that WordPress does, so your site will be slower. Another is that the API provides an easy way to escape queries with $wpdb->prepare(), which is a good security habit.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `global $post;` to the function, so that the `$post` variable will be available within the function's scope. Also, make sure your code is executing inside [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop). If the function is executing too early, then `$post` may not be available.

If neither of those things work, please post the full function and any other relevant code or details.

Comment: Sorted....! I used another query to find the current post's parent.. then compared it with 302..